# "ReactJs" a photo gallary for each product

Tags: reactjs

I wonder is there a way to do a simple photo gallary for each product with ReactJs,

something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fovzL.png) ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of packages for that, this is one of them:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-gallery